# ¿Como mandar datos de un modal dialog de bootstrap a una tabla en mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, bootstrap

Tengo una tabla en mysql llamada trabajos que tiene tres campos (Id_trabajo, Nombre_Trabajo y Costo) la cual tiene datos y los muestro en esta tabla en html

[image: Esta es la tabla que muestro en la pagina del sitio]

Ahora lo que quiero es que al seleccionar editar, pueda modificar el nombre y el costo y que este cambio se guarde también directamente en la base de datos, al dar click en editar tengo un modal-dialog como este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al dar click en actualizar no me hace nada,
este es mi código

```html
<form name="form2" method="post" action="actualizar_lista.php">
<div class="modal fade" id="edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">Editar informacion</h4>
            </div>
          
            <div class="modal-body">

                 <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="id" id="txt_id">
              </div>
            
              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Nombre del trabajo" id="txt_nombre">
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Costo" id="txt_costo">
              </div>
            
          
            <div class="modal-footer ">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Actualizar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

y este es mi codigo en php para la consulta

```html
 <!--LIBRERIAS DE ESTILOS DE BOOTSTRAP-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minium-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="consulta_lista.js">

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<?

  $conexion= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "registros");
  if($conexion)
    {
    
      //Variables
      $Id_Trabajo=$_POST['txt_id'];
      $Nombre_Trabajo = $_POST['txt_nombre'];
      $Costo=$_POST['txt_costo'];

     
      //realiza la consulta
      $consulta= "UPDATE trabajos set Nombre_Trabajo='$Nombre_Trabajo'and Costo='$Costo' WHERE Id_trabajo='$Id_Trabajo'";
  
  

      //para ejecutar consulta
      $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion ,$consulta);
 
        if ($resultado) 
          {   ?>

          <div class="alert alert-success">
            <strong>Datos guardados correctamente!</strong> 
            <a href="ingresar.html" class="alert-link">Volver</a>
          </div>
        <?}
    
        else { ?>
          <div class="alert alert-warning">
            <strong>Error al guardar los datos!</strong>
            <a href="ingresar.html" class="alert-link">Volver</a>
          </div>
         <?php } 
      
      }else{ 
        echo ""; 
        }
    
        mysqli_close($conexion);   
      ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

1.- Utiliza el evento click de JQuery para recibir el evento, dentro del evento recupera lel contenido del campo y realiza validaciones de los datos si asi lo requieres.

https://api.jquery.com/click/

2.- Una vez hecho lo anterior puedes mandar mediante ajax de jquery mandalo a una pagina donde hagas el proceso de conexion a tu DB

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form name="form2" method="POST" action="actualizar_lista.php">
  <div class="modal fade" id="edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">Editar informacion</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">

             <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="id" id="txt_id" name="txt_id">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Nombre del trabajo" id="txt_nombre" name="txt_nombre">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Costo" id="txt_costo" name="txt_costo">
          </div>


      <div class="form-group" align="center">

     <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-warning" name="btn"  id="btn" value="Actualizar"/>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>


    Archivo Actualizar_lista.php

          include("conexion.php");
          $txt_id=$_POST["txt_id"];
          $txt_nombre=$_POST["txt_nombre"];
          $txt_costo=$_POST["txt_costo"];
    $sql=mysqli_query($conexion,"update nombretabla set nombre=$txt_nombre, costo=$txt_costo where id=$txt_id");
    if ($conexion->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Actualizado Correctamente";
     }
```

Comment: Hola Rastalovely y bienvenido a SO en español. ¿podrías expandir un poco tu respuesta? Aunque puede ser aceptable en ciertos casos publicar únicamente código es importante dar una explicación que lo acompañe.

Answer (score 0):

Si fuese mi caso, yo usaria ajax.

1. Pondría un div dentro de la ventana modal que contenga solo el form con el botón.
2. Obtendría el valor (id que deseo editar).con el botón editar.
   Con mi `ajax` lo mandaría a un archivo aparte que  contendría todo la estructura `html` pero ¡ojo! debe estar dentro del php, en donde realizaría la consulta y traería los datos de ese id. Imprimo mi estructura `html` con sus datos en el -"value" con un "echo ".
3. Una vez hecho esto ya podrás ver tu ventana modal con los datos del id seleccionado.
4. En tu `PHP` que contiene el update solo recibe los datos. y actualiza.

Perdón por no anexar ejemplo. Pero te anexo una pagina que me ayudo en su momento a realizar algo parecido a tu pregunta https://mimentevuela.wordpress.com/2015/08/09/busqueda-instantanea-con-ajax-php-y-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Procura no concatenar en la consulta los datos ingresados por el usuario, de lo contrario serás vulnerable a [SQLi](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL). Además, tu código se puede organizar mejor si no mezclas vistas con backend. Puedes ver más sobre *separación de intereses* [aquí](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

**editar.php**

```
// variables
$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
$id_trabajo = $data[0]['id_trabajo'];
$nombre_trabajo = $data[1]['nombre_trabajo'];
$costo = $data[2]['costo'];

// realiza la consulta
$query = "UPDATE trabajos SET nombre_trabajo=?, costo=? WHERE id_trabajo=?";
$pstmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$pstmt->bind_param("sdi", $id_trabajo, $nombre_trabajo, $costo);

if($pstmt->execute($pstmt)) {
  json_encode(array("status" => "OK"));
} else {
  json_encode(array(
    "status" => "FAIL",
    "error" => $conn->error
  ));
}
```

**modal**

Por cuestiones semánticas es mejor que utilices formularios aunque uses AJAX. Esto ayuda a indentificar rápidamente que ese grupo de datos se enviará al servidor.

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <form class="modal-content" action="actualizar_trabajo.php" method="POST">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" 
                data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Editar trabajo</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control " type="hidden" placeholder="id" name="txt_id">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Nombre del trabajo" name="txt_nombre">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Costo" name="txt_costo">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.modal form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    type: $(this).attr('method'),
    data: { data: $(this).serializeArray() }
  })
  .done(function(response) {
    if(response.status === "OK") {
      $('.modal').modal('hide');
    } else {
      // mostrar el error al usuario
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Estimado falta agregar el atributo name para cada uno de los campos del formulario, para que luego se puedan tomar los valores a través del array $_POST['nombre_del_campo']:

```html
<input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="id" id="txt_id" name="txt_id">
```